# Reading a file word by word with no ending chars

Tags: c

I have this small program in C that reads through a file a compares word by word,
how can I assure that words like "this," won't be read as a word? I would like it to read as "this"

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./sw <word> <filename> \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    char* word = argv[1];
    const char* filename = argv[2];
    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    //Assuming one word can not have more than 250 chars
    char w[250], check_eof;
    do 
    {
        check_eof = fscanf(file, "%s", w);
        if(strcmp(word, w) == 0)
        {
            printf("W : %s \n", w);
        }
    } while(check_eof != EOF);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that [`scanf` (and family)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) separates strings on white-space. You could possibly use the `"%["` format to list a negative set of non-word characters, but it's not really a solution I recommend. Instead I recommend you read character-by-character and youself check if the character is a "word" character, or a separator character.

Comment: Ok, it makes sense, but instead of searching char by char, could I use fscanf and then examinate the word's last char only?

Comment: There are many sentences in just about all European languages that can contain multiple consecutive punctuation characters

Comment: Good point there! So, is there a way, checking it char by char, to know if it's a "word" character or not? Other than hard coding every single one of them with ORs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code below, I use [isalpha()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/) and I copy the result string in a new buffer named `res`. However, this procedure can be done in-place, but I'll leave now for the sake of simplicity.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <ctype.h> // for isalpha()

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char* word = "this";
    const char* filename = "test.txt";
    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    //Assuming one word can not have more than 250 chars
    // ATTENTION, it is 249 chars, do NOT forget of the null terminator
    char w[250], res[250];
    int check_eof; // should be of type int, for EOF checking
    do
    {
        check_eof = fscanf(file, "%s", w);
        // what if 'word' appears as the last word
        // in the file? You should check for eof
        // right after fscanf()
        if(check_eof == EOF)
          break;
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        while (w[i]) // parse what we read
        {
          if (isalpha(w[i]))
            res[j++] = w[i]; // keep only the alphabetic chars
          i++;
        }
        res[j] = '\0'; // it should be a null terminated string
        if(strcmp(word, res) == 0) // compare to 'res' now
        {
            printf("W : %s \n", res);
        }
    } while(1); // the terminating step is inside the body now
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much guys, last question, why res[j++] = w[i] instead of res[j]?

Comment: Pleasure @CarlosPereira. When we write a char to `res`, we want to write the next char to `res` in the next position, thus we have to increment `j`. We can do `res[j] = w[i]; j++;`. Nice question, here is my +1.

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you @G.Samaras but is there a way to implement in your code a line counter? To keep track of the line the word was found? I tried comparing to "\n", but it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Yes @CarlosPereira. Just outside from the do-while, declare a counter and initialize it to 0. Every time you read a word, you want this counter to be incremented by one, so just after `fscanf()`, do a `++` on the counter. Then, if you find the word, you can use the counter, which keeps the information you need.

Comment: I think you are assuming that there's only one word per line @G.Samaras

Comment: Not really, I just misunderstood the question @CarlosPereira, sorry! You are in the right track. However, `fscanf()` won't read the newline, it will skip it and will fetch the first word from the next line. That means that you should change the function for reading and there are plenty of solutions, not sure which one to suggest. Seems like its time for your 2nd question in SO. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check if a char belongs to a word like this

```
int c = fgetc(file);
if ((c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')) {
    // c belongs to a word
    word[n++] = c;
} else {
    // end of word
    if (strncmp(word, w, n) == 0) {
        // word and w match!
    }
}
```

If you `#include <ctype.h>`, then you can call [`isalpha(c)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/) instead to test it.

Comment: Actually you can use `isalpha()` in pure C too. It's where it belongs to.